# MS SQL server + spring integration

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-mvc, integration

Can you suggest how to integrate spring mvc with ms sql server ?
(Before it I used with mongodb, spring mvc + spring-data-db)

I am looking for best practice for integrate spring mvc and ms sql server.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use proper driver for MS SQL and Hibernate dialect and you are fine.

P.S. Way back when I had to use MS SQL jTDS driver proved to fit my requirements better than one provided by MS